# How indexing works in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. This seems like a basic question to ask. But I really want to understand what is happening here

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
tempdata = np.random.random(5)
myseries_one = pd.Series(tempdata)
myseries_two = pd.Series(data = tempdata, index = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
myseries_three = pd.Series(data = tempdata, index = [10,11,12,13,14])


myseries_one
Out[1]: 
0    0.291293
1    0.381014
2    0.923360
3    0.271671
4    0.605989
dtype: float64

myseries_two
Out[2]: 
a    0.291293
b    0.381014
c    0.923360
d    0.271671
e    0.605989
dtype: float64

myseries_three
Out[3]: 
10    0.291293
11    0.381014
12    0.923360
13    0.271671
14    0.605989
dtype: float64
```

Indexing first element from each dataframe

```
myseries_one[0] #As expected
Out[74]: 0.29129291112626043

myseries_two[0] #As expected
Out[75]: 0.29129291112626043

myseries_three[0]
KeyError:0
```

Doubt1 :-Why this is happenening ? Why myseries_three[0] gives me a keyError ?
what we meant by calling myseries_one[0] , myseries_one[0] or myseries_three[0] ? Does calling this way mean we are calling by rownames ?

Doubt2 :-Is rownames and rownumber in Python works as different as rownames and rownumber in R ?

```
myseries_one[0:2]
Out[78]: 
0    0.291293
1    0.381014
dtype: float64

myseries_two[0:2]
Out[79]: 
a    0.291293
b    0.381014
dtype: float64

myseries_three[0:2]
Out[80]: 
10    0.291293
11    0.381014
dtype: float64
```

Doubt3:- If calling myseries_three[0] meant calling by rownames then how myseries_three[0:3] producing the output ? does myseries_three[0:4] mean we are calling by rownumber ? Please explain and guide. I am migrating from R to python. so its a bit confusing for me.

Comment: For the first doubt, you are getting the `key error`, I guess, because, index `0` does not exist since you are explicitly identifying the indices. To fix it you can use the following: `myseries_three.iloc[0]`.

Comment: This looks like a curiosity that pandas is helping you in the `myseries_two` example, for Series the indexing is label based so it should've raised a `KeyError` for the second example but it decided to use position based indexing as a convenience for you, your understanding is not incorrect, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics

Comment: Adding to @Dataman comment. In _three,  replace "14" with '0', and see the results. If keys are  'text' then number indexing 'still' works. if keys are numbers, then pandas returns key searched for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are attempting to slice with `myseries[something]`, the `something` is often ambiguous.  You are highlighting a case of that ambiguity.  In your case, pandas is trying to help you out by guessing what you mean.

```
myseries_one[0] #As expected
Out[74]: 0.29129291112626043
```

`myseries_one` has integer labels.  It would make sense that when you attempt to slice with an integer that you intend to get the element that is labeled with that integer.  It turns out, that you have an element labeled with `0` an so that is returned to you.

```
myseries_two[0] #As expected
Out[75]: 0.29129291112626043
```

`myseries_two` has string labels.  It's highly unlikely that you meant to slice this series with a label of `0` when labels are all strings.  So, pandas assumes that you meant a position of `0` and returns the first element (thanks pandas, that was helpful).

```
myseries_three[0]
KeyError:0
```

`myseries_three` has integer labels and you are attempting to slice with an integer... perfect.  Let's just get that value for you... `KeyError`.  Whoops, that index label does not exist.  In this case, it is safer for pandas to fail than to guess that maybe you meant to slice by position.  The documentation even suggests that if you want to remove the ambiguity, use `loc` for label based slicing and `iloc` for position based slicing.

Let's try `loc`

```
myseries_one.loc[0]
0.29129291112626043

myseries_two.loc[0]
KeyError:0 

myseries_three.loc[0]
KeyError:0
```

Only `myseries_one` has a label `0`.  The other two return `KeyError`s

Let's try `iloc`

```
myseries_one.iloc[0]
0.29129291112626043

myseries_two.iloc[0]
0.29129291112626043

myseries_three.iloc[0]
0.29129291112626043
```

They all have a position of `0` and return the first element accordingly.

---

For the range slicing, pandas decides to be less interpretive and sticks to positional slicing for the integer slice `0:2`.  Keep in mind.  Actual real people (the programmers writing pandas code) are the ones making these decisions.  When you are attempting to do something that is ambiguous, you may get varying results.  To remove ambiguity, use `loc` and `iloc`.

***`iloc`***

```
myseries_one.iloc[0:2]

0    0.291293
1    0.381014
dtype: float64

myseries_two.iloc[0:2]

a    0.291293
b    0.381014
dtype: float64

myseries_three.iloc[0:2]

10    0.291293
11    0.381014
dtype: float64
```

***`loc`***

```
myseries_one.loc[0:2]

0    0.291293
1    0.381014
2    0.923360
dtype: float64

myseries_two.loc[0:2]

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <type 'int'>

myseries_three.loc[0:2]

Series([], dtype: float64)
```