# Pandas value_counts returns error depending on the value type of the series

Tags: python, pandas

why does the first DF returns a key error at 0?

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,2,1]})  
t1.c1.value_counts()[0]  # key error: 0

t2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','b','a']})  
t2.c1.value_counts()[0]  # prints 2
```

Thanks to @anky_91's link to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917945/how-indexing-works-in-pandas), here is the answer:

```
#t1's output
index  value
2      2
1      2

#t2's output
index  value
b      2
a      2
```

When `t1[0]` is executed, it looks for an index labeled as 0, which is equivalent to `t1.loc[0]`, this would return a `key error` because there is no `0` in t1's index.

When `t2[0]` is executed, it also looks for an index labeled as 0. It should return `key error` as well since there is no such value in t2's index. However, `Pandas` is trying to be smart here `t2's index is all character based, but an integer is passed in. Thus, I would assume you are looking for the value stored at 'position 0' rather than at`a label named 0`.

Basically, Pandas translated `t2[0] -> t2.loc[0], whoops t2's index contains characters only so try position based -> t2.iloc[0]`

Comment: shouldn't you call `test.c1.value_counts().iloc[0]` for both?

Comment: or you should convert the dtype to string `test.astype(str).c1.value_counts()[0]` but `iloc[]` is preferred. :)

Comment: @anky_91 true, but why does the second example work?

Comment: check this answer by piRsquared :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917945/how-indexing-works-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```py
test.c1.value_counts()
```

will give you a series.
You can use:

```
type(test.c1.value_counts())
```

to see the type.
If you have an int value in your index of a series, when you try `Series[int_value]` it will first find if this `int_value` is in your index, then you will get the error.
You can try:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a',1.2,1.2]})
test.c1.value_counts()[0]
```

This code will get no error. Just because there is no int in the index of `test.c1.value_counts()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the answer without the [0], you will see what's happening.

In the first instance:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,2,1]})  
test.c1.value_counts()

2    2
1    2
```

and in the second instance:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','b','a']})  
test.c1.value_counts() 

a    2
b    2
```

So when you use [0] in the first instance, there is no index '0', so you get an error. If you use [2] or [1] in the first instance, you will get 2.

In the second instance, since there are letters in the index, you will get [0] and [1] returning 2. Also, you can use ['a'] and ['b'] and also return 2 for each in the second instance.

I'm not sure if you are looking for the value at the index for the total count of items. If you are seeking the total count of items, you should consider replacing the [0] with .count()

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,2,1]})  
test.c1.value_counts().count()  # prints 2

test = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','b','a']})  
test.c1.value_counts().count()  # prints 2
```