# Confusing indexer of pandas

Tags: pandas

I found the bracket indexer([]) very confusing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

aa = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(aa)
df
```

output

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

Then I tried to index it with []

```
df[1]
```

output as below, it seems it gets me the values of a column

```
0    2
1    5
2    8
```

but..when I do

```
df[1:3]
```

it gets me the rows...

```
    0   1   2
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

Besides that, it does not allow me  to do

```
df[1,2]
```

it gives me error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 19' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df[1,2]

File d:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3458, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3456 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3457     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3458 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3459 if is_integer(indexer):
   3460     indexer = [indexer]

File d:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py:388, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    386         except ValueError as err:
    387             raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 388     raise KeyError(key)
    389 return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: (1, 2)
```

Should I avoid using [] and always use loc and iloc instead ?

Comment: Use ```df[[1,2]]``` instead

Comment: Checkout the Pandas indexing reference. It explains why a single item or a list of items selects columns while slicing selects rows when using `[]`. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920717/1328439 Might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, if you want to select values by numeric index, you use `iloc`. a dataframe has 2 axes, so to select a specific cell you have to specify both axes (row and column). see the code.

```
df.iloc[0,0] # this should return the value 1
df.iloc[0,:] # this returns the first row
df.iloc[:,0] # first column
df.iloc[:2,:2] # this returns a slice of the dataframe which is the first two rows with the first two columns
```

to select values by labels (column names and index labels), use `loc`